# Running R from batch file

Tags: r, batch-file

I want to run an *R* script with the help of batch files so that I can automate some processes. I am using **Windows 8.1 PRO**.

Currently my `.bat` file looks like this:

```
@echo off

R CMD BATCH C:\Users\bg901224\Desktop\lof.R
```

And the R script (`lof.R`) looks like this:

```
data10301 <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\bg901224\\Desktop\\data.csv")

library(Rlof)
score.lof <- lof(data10301[, c("CE11000_ERLOS", "Z_NSR")],10)
data10301$LOF <- score.lof

write.csv(data10301[,c("CE11000_KUNRG","LOF")], 
          "C:\\Users\\bg901224\\Desktop\\results.csv",
          row.names = FALSE)
```

The task is to run the `lof` function from [`Rlof`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=Rlof) package, added the results as a column to the `data.frame` holding the data and save it on my desktop as a `.csv`.

When I do it manually it works perfectly, but when I call the script with the `.bat` file above I do not get any output. What would be the correct way to call my script as I have tried 3 different ways and none of them worked?

Comment: R -> R.NET -> C#. Perhaps, this path may be tried to run .bat file.

Comment: @ErdoganCEVHER I don't really understand what you mean.. Can you give me an example so i can try to mimic it on my machine?

Comment: Nevermind...

this seemed to do the job:

@echo off

cd C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\bin\x64
R CMD BATCH C:\Users\bg901224\Desktop\lof.R

Comment: Your handling seems to me problematic. Your question and handling the prob do not match each other. The answer to your problem (with wrong handling) is via R.NET: You can run R code from C# via R.NET. That's why, via C# interface, you can obtain ".exe" that can run R code. Then, thinking this way, there is no much difference running .exe or .bat from Windows command prompt. BUT: Your handling your prob should be like this: `Rlof::lof` returns a matrix. You can extract that matrix directly to R's console or to an .xlsx via `write.xlsx` function of the `xlsx` package.

Comment: From scientific point, UGARTE2016 "Probability and Statistics with R" 2E p. 838, "12.11.2.2 Identifying Unusual Observations" covers "outliers" perfectly. R code of Ch.12: [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alanarnholt/PASWR2E-Rscripts/master/ChapterScripts/chapter12.R). R Code 12.26 -12.29 covers outliers. You may desire to glimpse at this [link](http://stat-ata-asu.github.io/STT3851ClassRepo/Rmarkdown/Cross-ValidationInClassHO.pdf) work as well that covers "12.12 Model Validation" p.862 of the same book.

Comment: Thank you for the information!

Comment: Have you tried using RScript.exe instead of R CMD BATCH?  Also, remove the @echo off for troubleshooting...

Comment: @PhilC It worked like this as well:

(add)echo off
cd C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\bin\x64
Rscript --vanilla C:\Users\bg901224\Desktop\lof.R

What is the difference between having echo off and not? Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: @Echo off prevents the commands that are run from showing in the command window (you only get results).  For troubleshooting, it can be useful to leave echo on and see which command is returning which message.

Comment: @PhilC Yes, in case something does not work properly i can use it to check the problem. Thank you!